# How to instantiate class (from array) inside the loop

Tags: php, laravel

I want to instantiate class inside the loop, I've tried doing this:

```
<?php
   use App\Caves_demographic_info;
   use App\Caves_current_uses;
   use App\Caves_flora_outside;

   public function get_page4_contd_data($id) {
     $tables = [
        'Caves_demographic_info', 'Caves_current_uses', 'Caves_flora_outside',
     ];


    for($index = 0; $index < count($tables); $index++) {
        ${$tables[$index]."_model"} = new $tables[$index];
    }

   }
?>
```

It produces the error 'Class {class_name} not found', Is it possible to do that inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems right, can you try (with namespace)

```
$className = 'App\' . $tables[$index];
$class = new $className;
```

So something like this in your example:

```
 $tables = [
    'App\Caves_demographic_info', 
    'App\Caves_current_uses', 
    'App\Caves_flora_outside',
 ];

for($index = 0; $index < count($tables); $index++) {
    ${$tables[$index]."_model"} = new $tables[$index];
}
```

Comment: still not working.. second approach produces same error. first approach produces unexpected error

Comment: Can you try it with namespace? I just tried in my code, with full namespace it should work

Comment: how would you parse the backslash in the string though?

Comment: happy coding! :)

Comment: `$className = 'App\' . $tables[$index];` should be `$className = 'App\\' . $tables[$index];` (escaped backslash).

Comment: Doesnt need the backslashes for me